Podman "no route to host" when pushing to container registry with sudo, but works without sudo
I am encountering a problem with Podman on my system when I try to push images to a local registry. First, I start the registry container with sudo.
$ sudo podman container run -dt -p 5000:5000 --name registry  docker.io/library/registry:2

I can check the logs :
$ sudo podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                         COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS             PORTS                   NAMES
<id>  docker.io/library/registry:2  /etc/docker/regis...  26 minutes ago  Up 26 minutes ago  0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp  registry

$ sudo podman logs registry 
WARN[0000] No HTTP secret provided - generated random secret. This may cause problems with uploads if multiple registries are behind a load-balancer. To provide a shared secret, fill in http.secret in the configuration file or set the REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET environment variable.  go.version=go1.20.8 instance.id=id service=registry version=2.8.3
INFO[0000] redis not configured                          go.version=go1.20.8 instance.id=<id>service=registry version=2.8.3
INFO[0000] using inmemory blob descriptor cache          go.version=go1.20.8 instance.id=<id> service=registry version=2.8.3
INFO[0000] Starting upload purge in 31m0s                go.version=go1.20.8 instance.id=<id> service=registry version=2.8.3
INFO[0000] listening on [::]:5000                        go.version=go1.20.8 instance.id=<id> service=registry version=2.8.3

Then, I get this error when I try to push my image :
$ sudo podman push localhost:5000/my-image --tls-verify=false
Getting image source signatures
WARN[0012] failed, retrying in 1s ... (1/3). Error: trying to reuse blob sha256:<sha256>at destination: pinging container registry localhost:5000: Get "http://localhost:5000/v2/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: no route to host 
Getting image source signatures
WARN[0026] failed, retrying in 1s ... (2/3). Error: trying to reuse blob sha256:<sha> at destination: pinging container registry localhost:5000: Get "http://localhost:5000/v2/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: no route to host 
Getting image source signatures
WARN[0038] failed, retrying in 1s ... (3/3). Error: trying to reuse blob sha256:<sha> at destination: pinging container registry localhost:5000: Get "http://localhost:5000/v2/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: no route to host 
Getting image source signatures
Error: trying to reuse blob sha256:<sha> at destination: pinging container registry localhost:5000: Get "http://localhost:5000/v2/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connect: no route to host

However, if I do the same without sudo, it is working correctly.
I also tried to do it with sudo -E but I got the same error.
Any ideas ?

I found a solution :
sudo podman run -d --network=host --name registry registry:2

use of --network=host fixed this issue.
This may not be the best method in terms of security.
